# Best way to defend against a army of 100 thousand?

Tags: internal-consistency, medieval, military, military-defense, strategy

So our protagonist city-state is a decently sized, rich in resources, and populated(think 100 thousand people) kingdom with Early Medieval Dark Ages technology(no gunpowder or cannons). The attacker has about the same amount of resources, but a whole ten times the population, and now they want to conquer our city-state. Their technology is roughly equivalent to that of the late iron age, and they can mobilize a 100 thousand strong invasion force. Assuming that the entire city state can mobilize maybe 25 thousand people to work for the state, and there are 12 months to prepare for the invasion, what would be the best way to prevent the attackers from overrunning the city-state? No magic, and there are no defenses currently in place.

Edit: The territory of our city-state is roughly 1600 square kilometers, around 40 by 40 kilometers, and have basically all the resources you can ask for. Describe both the defense preparations and the battle itself.

Tactical And Strategic Info:[image]

Our city-state's forces: 10 thousand regular troops, 50% infantry, 20% archers, 30% calvary
Equipment: What you would expect from the crusades

The invasion force: 100 thousand troops, 99% infantry, 1% archers
Equipment: What rome had during the early republic

Goal: Prevent the invasion force from getting inside the city, make the force retreat or kill all of them.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117102/discussion-on-question-by-sync-best-way-to-defend-against-a-army-of-100-thousand).

Comment: This kind of question has always been allowed on WB as on topic since they are more about identifying and exploiting the systems of your world than they are about character driven choices.  The only meta question I can find that seems to question tactics questions is this https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4657/the-problem-of-my-question-regarding-battle-tactics-against-robots one which just stipulates that you should include enough of a reffeance point for an informed answer.  This question does that, so I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: Precisely, thank you for checking the meta.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> "Amateurs talk about tactics, but professionals study logistics."
> ~ Gen. Robert H. Barrow

The keys to victory here will be buying time and cutting supplies.

You will want to begin by building a decent city wall.  Most classical cities used them because very few were actually good at siegecraft.  While the Romans eventually got okay at it, most walled cities were simply considered unassailable or otherwise tooks over a year of siege to capture.  Instead most battles were actually fought over farmland and other resources that laid outside of the city.

Furthermore, the river means you can make a flooded moat around the wall which would prevent any method of Roman era siege craft that would allow for a quick storming of your city. Your relatively large number of archers also means that it would be very difficult for the attackers to fill it in to make a land bridge over which to bring ladders or a siege tower. So, if the attackers want your city, they will need to starve you out of it.

Knowing when the enemy is attacking 12 months in advance is also a HUGE tactical advantage here.  That gives you time to plan your crops and growing seasons to harvest all of your food just before the enemy arrives and bring it into the city just ahead of the attack.  This will prevent the invaders from feeding off of your land, and maximize how long you can stay in your city.  And, don't just hoard food.  You will need to stockpile firewood, medicine, arrows, and clean water too.

Classical armies this size needed a lot of food which often had to be captured from the defender's farmlands, or the campaign would fail.  Long supply lines coupled with large armies have been the bane of many classical era generals.  Once the attacking army realizes that there are no local farmlands to exploit, they will likely be forced to disband a large portion of their troops and rely on wagon train to bring in all of the food to supply their army which will be very expensive for the invaders and ultimately unsustainable.

This is where your cavalry becomes extra important.  Inside of the city horses are useless, but before the attack you can break them into many smaller skirmishing regiments and have them sneak around the attacking army.  You can position them at intervals along the supply lines of the attacking army.  Because the invaders have no cavalry to counter them, your horsemen can hit-and-run the supply wagons with immunity. Find a small convoy, just hit it.  See a bigger one, ride ahead to merge with other regiments until you have enough men to take it.

The horse raiders will steal what they can to keep themselves provisioned and burn the rest.

Even if the attackers try to adapt by breaking off a massive force to defend the supplies, you generally can not march long distances in full battle formations; so, such caravans will naturally form long columns in many places which would be vulnerable to hit and run maneuvers where your cavalry could ride in, burn the supplies, and ride off before the infantry can mount a proper defense.

While the defenders might have enough food for a year or more rationed away in anticipation of this battle, the attackers will be out of supplies within weeks.  The attackers will be forced to retreat all the way home having never been able to force a single pitched battle with the smaller defending army... or if they wait too long to realise how truly screwed they are, they will be forced to surrender giving the smaller state a massive supply of captured weapons and armor and the ability to ransom the army back to the attacking nation at a price that would prevent them from funding a follow up invasion for years to come.

All this said, perhaps you still fail to cut their supply lines; so, it is good to have a Plan B.  Since the defenders had enough time to store a bunch of drinkable water anyway, they do not need the river for its water. So, just before the siege begins you could also dump a few carts of dung into the river upstream of yourself.  The attackers will not expect the water upstream of your city to be contaminated; so, on top of starvation, you can also make them sick.  If you make the attackers sick enough, they will not be in good enough of health to fight or retreat; so, this too could make it easy to force their surrender.

Comment: "Amateurs talk about tactics, but professionals study logistics."

Comment: That right there is the most correct statement I have ever heard about about strategy in war.

Comment: If that moat is still connected to the river, maybe the city can go fishing in it too. An extra source of protein, if they have very long fishing lines. Also, all the dirt they excavate has to be good for something; some kind of earthworks?

Comment: i am not recommend the horse to hide on wood/forest though its dangerous for the horse from tripping or you can lose your momentum due to the branch and fallen log around or startle the horse for whatever reason which may also applied to the cave, unless this is foraged forest which is cleaned by the peasant which make it hard to make an ambush, not considering you need to train the horse not to make a sound.

Comment: rather than making an ambush its far better to direct confront using the cavalry to destroy or steal their supply, since enemy is mainly infantry anyway they wont be able to chase your cavalry or outmaneuver them, unless they know how to form wagon fort to protect the supply.

Comment: @LiJun My main point is to keep them out of sight until you are ready to attack, but that is a reasonable argument.

Comment: This war will come down to who gets dysentery first. The city, overloaded with the influx of residents from neighboring farmland, or the invaders, camped around the city in unsanitary clumps.

Comment: @CaM If it becomes a prolonged siege, then this is true. That is why the superiority of calvary is so important to the defense strategy. The point is to not let the siege drag on long enough that sickness decides the outcome, but to force the attackers into food shortages as quickly as possible.

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson the problem with fishing (and drinking) from the river is that 25 to 50% of your attacking force is upstream. And odds are high that they're ALSO fishing. AND using the river as their latrine, which impacts the city's health in serious ways. And if they're not fishing, they may intentionally poison the river periodically to starve the city out.

Comment: @Sync:  Amateurs talk about tactics, professionals study logistics, winners realize that investing resources in one town at the mouth of the stratigic pass is pointless and it's better to let the town fall and hit the supply lines as they go through the choke point of the river valley in the mountains where an effective guerilla campaign can be waged against the enemy.

Comment: @hszmv The OP stipulates that this is a city-state. So, this is not just 1 town, but the entire state's urban center.  If the city falls, then you don't really have much of anything left worth fighting for.

Answer (score 4):

**The best defense is a good offense.**

I conclude these are not warlike people in this area, if the city as it stands has no defenses but is next door to a (newly!) aggressive neighbor.  Aggressive neighbor has apparently never been a threat until now.  Maybe they are not good at it.  I am betting that if you have no defenses your neighbor does not either.

Your aggressor has only infantry which means they will attack by land, on foot, so they cannot be that far away.

You have 3000 cavalrymen.  They can cover the distance fast, before your enemy knows it is under attack.   Use them to attack the capital of your enemy.  Your foot soldiers will be right behind coming as quick as they can.  Take the capitol and the leaders there who have decided on this warlike course of action.

Treat the citizenry kindly!  Do not sack the city!  You need these people on your side!

Then make clear to the people of your neighboring country that their leaders are idiots.  Display captured leaders in clown suits.  Your two countries have always been good peaceful neighbors and you like it that way.  Fighting is wasteful and stupid.  Put in a government in your neighboring country that feels that way.  Maybe whatever government these new bozos kicked out - bring back the exiled prince.  He will be grateful!

Take the siege engines and armaments from the neighboring city and burn them in a big pile.

---

Go to work on a freaking wall for your city when you get back, already!

Comment: Alright, wall it is...oops the neighbors are back

Comment: Did you skip the part about installing the new government?  <hint: that new government is really you!>

Comment: I didn't, the warlike neighbors of the neighbors overthrew the new government and are attacking us!!!

Comment: Legit the ancient world in a nutshell(ehem Three Kingdoms)

Comment: 3000 cavalry would not be nearly enough to overrun the capitol.  Even if they are dumb enough not to have a city wall (which would never happen on city of that size in that era) the enemy capitol has a population of about 1 million. Since they are a classical civilization, about 50,000-200,000 of those people will probably be citizens who already own their own weapons.  In the confines of the enemy streets especially you cavalry will be trapped and slaughtered by the sheer size of the enemy's militia response.

Comment: Also, even if the city as a whole is not defensible, the palace probably will be.  It only takes a few inches of oak door to turn your cavalry charge into a siege where you will be hopelessly outnumbered by a larger force closing in around you.

Comment: @Nosajimiki - the strategy as I laid out would work only in this world where a large rich city can come to exist with zero defenses of any kind.  I imagine these people like the Eloi in The Time Machine.

Comment: Okay, I've rethought my stance on this answer, and I can think of 1 historical case where something like this sort of happened: the Spartan conquest of Messenia.  The Messenians outnumbers the Spartans ~10 to 1 but were still conquered.  Neither civilization had walls not because they were peaceful, but because their civilizations were both in such turmoil following the bronze age collapse; however, the key difference is that Messenia was a very sprawled out civilization of farmers with no center of power at all whereas Sparta was concentrated and organized.

Comment: Since the smaller state here has so much cavalry and archers we can assume they are in fact the more militant civilization like the Spartans.  If this is that case here, it could be that there is no enemy capital at all to conquer, but instead the enemy is a confederation of weaker towns.   So, your "Spartan" army could go out can conquer each enemy town 1 at a time before the the enemy could amase a proper army anywhere to stop you.

Comment: But if this is the case, you do not want to split your army, you will want to march together and united fighting many smaller battles with your 1 army as opposed to hoping to gain anything from a single large battle.

Comment: @Nosajimiki - Yes; to cut off the head you need a head.  I figured go after whomever the leaders are because aggression seems like a novel idea for these folks and so probably reflects new leadership somewhere..  If there are no leaders then it wont work and OP should go to work on the city walls.  A leaderless confederacy is going to struggle with each faction supplying  their own troops during the siege, and they will be fighting each other within a couple of months.

Answer (score 4):

First I would build a city wall, the best that could be made depending on local materials. Ideally stone, but there might not be enough time or materials for that, failing that mud brick, Earth and timber or a combination. A substantial fortification of some form would be very doable within a year including a wide deep ditch.

Second ensure that everything edible within the approach corridor of the invading army has been removed or destroyed along with as much wood as possible.

Third ensure the city is fully provisioned that there a huge amount of arrows are available and the citizens are gainfully employed in harvest, construction or other military preparation such as training as militia.

Fourth position the vast bulk of the cavalry out of the city (with supplies) and as soon as the enemy are detected send a signal to activate the cavalry force.

When the cavalry force is signaled to attack they move out in a very in a wide arc well out to one side of the attackers and the overrun the enemy supply train from behind kill or capture the horses and burn the wagons. They then move forward enmass and attack the enemy from behind causing a great deal of chaos.

The defenders in the city should be able to hold out against initial attacks with stout fortifications and a vast superiority in archers.

The cavalry retreat before any serious resistance can be mounted and disappear over the horizon. Scouts watch what the enemy is doing and large scale raids are made on the enemy at night on an adhoc basis. After some time the enemy would be worn down, starved and dispirited and likely to withdraw. Prisoners could be set free with stories that encouraged defection.

Comment: We appear to have both come up with the exact same battle strategy almost to a the t, lol.

Comment: Yes indeed! I suppose it is the logical choice.

Answer (score 4):

If it comes down to similarly-equipped-mass-vs-mass fighting, then the small city has already lost.

- Give the small city a small technological advantage. Steel swords against bronze. Bigger horses or faster horses or better armor. Trebuches vs catapults, etc. Under the right conditions (usually involving surprise), that small advantage can make an enormous difference.
- Use diplomacy and intrigue effectively to sap the enemy's strength before the invasion begins. Promote the Emperor's rivals so he's afraid to leave the palace and lead the invasion in person. Get efficient generals replaced by buffoons...or venals who can be bribed. Plant rumors of alliances and other deceptions to shift the invasion plan into the wrong season, or before the invading army is ready. Encourage a second army of merchants, camp-followers, crooks, and others to accompany the invasion force, slowing it down and distracting the leadership.
- Use chemical and biological warfare in depth: Poison all of the water supplies that the invaders must use on their route of march and for their siege. Put your plague-carriers and other infectious into uniform and send them out as "scouts" to be captured by the invaders as they cross the border.
- Use natural, artificial, and imaginary (deception) obstacles to slow the advance, cut off supplies, and protect rear-area ambush forces. The poisons and sicknesses need time to be effective. Try to slow their advance to just a few miles per day. Flood roads and fords, set avalanches and rockslides in the passes, burn the fields and forests -- all timed to divide up their forces and scramble their units and communications. Those rear-area ambush forces should target small, high-value targets - like message runners.
- As the advance bogs down, agents in the palace should deceive the Emperor into anger at the remaining competent officers, and get them replaced with buffoons, too. Encourage the Emperor to set impossible, unachievable goals that will dismay his minions and soldiers slogging along the road. You want to encourage tens of thousands of desertions, first hiding among the camp followers, then scampering back towards home each night.

By the time the invaders arrive at the city, they have already been through an ordeal. You want them to arrive weeks later than they expected, exhausted, sick, starving, badly led, disgruntled, and at half-strength. A hollow force.

The combination of 1) The hollow invasion force, 2) The city's extra-strong wall, 3) The city's well-fed, well-led, well-equipped, high-morale defenders, and 4) The secret-weapon at the critical moment will combine to enable their much-smaller force to scythe through the attackers to victory.

...oh, and remember to bribe the attacking general to launch un-coordinated and un-supported attacks to waste much of their numerical advantage, to change the plan mid-battle, and to generally cause chaos within the attacker's ranks. The bribe may cost a lot, but it's worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

The other comments have laid out what the defenders should do to a T ( I especially like Nosajimiki's logistics-based answer).  Basically the attackers in this scenario are the ones with the harder task.  Taking a walled city in antiquity (or even modern-day without artillery) is HARD.  Logistics in the ancient world was even harder.  So what I will attempt to do is a frame change describing the attacker's best-chance strategy given the situation you described.

1: Their angle of direct attack (overland from the northeast per your drawing) is hugely sub-optimal.  The defenders have superior numbers of horse, and a year to both stockpile supplies and strip the area.  The tyranny of supply means you'd be tied to oxen-pulled supply carts that quickly end up carrying more food for the oxen than supplies for your army.  (for more details check out [THIS](https://acoup.blog/2019/10/06/new-acquisitions-how-fast-do-armies-move/) lovely explanation.) Yeah it might be shortest "as the crow flies" but you may well starve to death before you get there and will certainly have a hard time supplying your forces overland for a siege.  Instead if possible they should march up the river, preferably from a point in their own or allied territory.  This will allow you to transport your supplies much easier, even if it is upriver.  It'll also allow you to bring more supplies, and they'll be better protected from enemy raiders.  (instead of a literally miles-long wagon train you can transport the same amount of supplies on 1-2 barges, allowing you to concentrate your defense.)
So we've got your army there.  Sure it might take a little longer going around rather than straight at the city, but this way is MUCH safer, and now your men are *less likely to starve to death! Huzzah!

2: Time to attack.  We're going to set out during the low-water period of the year, whatever that happens to be. The dry season, high summer, whenever.  The main thing is to have as little flow in that river as possible.  If the river is huge (talking Amazon/Mississippi) then the traditional "start of campaign season" will have to do.

3: How to take a walled city with a Legion.  Well let's assume that the city is well-stocked (they had a year to horde grain and time their harvests) and obviously they have plenty of water because of the river.  Heck, they probably have a moat in addition to a wall, which makes it essentially impossible to breach via the tech level the army has available.  But the river can also be a weakness.  I'm not sure how wide your river is, but there are a few options.

Option A: Dam the river.  The hardest-but-surest option.  Depending on flood plains, available knowledge base, and available supplies (can they get boats from upstream? Are there nearby forests?) you could just block most or all of the river's flow into the city.  As a city built on a river they are highly unlikely to have wells, large cisterns, or other sources of water.  You can't starve them out, but you can thirst them out!

B: Plague them out.  Your army intentionally spoils the river flowing into the city.  Use it as a latrine, dump offal into it, whatever nastiness you can think of.  Not going to work if the River is the size of the Amazon, Nile, or Mississippi, but if it's something small there's a chance you could befoul the river enough that those inside catch something horrible.  Walls are worthless without soldiers to defend them! You can also build catapults/ballista to lob the traditional carcasses into the city, but I don't know if your attackers are technologically sophisticated enough for that.

C: Coup de main.  They've got tons of supplies, good walls, probably a moat, and plenty of trained men.  But (given your description of medieval army vs roman-esque army) our infantry should be both better trained and better equipped.  Barring some sort of spycraft/traitor inside to open a gate, the best way in is going to be from the up-river gate.  Launch infantry assaults along both sides of the up-river gate with a rock-laden barge to slam into the gate itself.  With luck the gates break and a riverine assault can begin.  If they don't break perhaps (though we're stretching a bit now) assaulting troops could attempt to scale the wall from the barge itself.  This however is a long shot.  Really if "cut off their water supplies" or "give them cholera/typhoid/plague" doesn't work, there's really not a lot the attackers can do but settle in for a multi-year siege and hope their supply lasts longer than the defender's supply.  Or at least lasts long enough for someone in the city to get greedy/desperate enough to open a path from the inside.

Comment: thats what i think too, originally to use the river, but seeing the map river arrow is in the opposite direction of the invader i dont think its worth it, unless the wind direction is in the opposite to help invader sail, and the rest of the army can exhaust faster if they row it themselves.

Comment: The direction of the water also has some additional constraints: You can not dam the river without cutting off your own supplies and depending on how far away the attacking state is, you may not be able to contaminate it without poisoning their own city further downstream.